# SQL Join Issue with Nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, ssms

I have 7 tables I am using in a view.  For examples, I will be using these as my table names (The Fields within the table don't matter for this execpt that the PrimaryKey is tableName + ID)

Table 1.
Teacher

Table 2.
Student  (Exception-- Student has all the ids in it, from all the other 6 tables)

Table 3.
Science

Table 4.
Math

Table 5.
History

Table 6.
German

Table 7.
Language Arts

Now, All the tables from 3-7 have a relationship to Student from Table 2. And Student has a relationship to teacher.

My view currently works if any of my tables have any fields. and some can be null, it also works if any of my tables 3-7 are completely null, it will still display.

However, my current problem is, if my teacher has no students assigned to them, making tables 2-7 null, empty, etc.... My query doesnt even return the teacher info that is filled in... First name, last name, Date of birth, etc.

How can I Accomplish this?

I tried doing all left joins from all the tables, since the teacher can have null fields, I tried doing an inner join from dbo.Teacher as Teacher Inner Join dbo.Student on dbo.Student.TeacherID = Teacher.TeacherID but that didnt work.. I am at a loss...

```
SELECT  Teacher.TeacherID ,
        Student.StudentID ,
        Science.ScienceID ,
        History.HistoryID ,
        Math.MathID ,
        German.GermanID ,
        LanguageArts.LanguageArtsID
FROM    dbo.Teacher AS Teacher
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Student 
            ON dbo.Student.TeacherID = Teacher.TeacherID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Science AS Science 
            ON dbo.Student.ScienceID = Science.ScieneID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Math AS Math 
            ON dbo.Student.MathID = Math.MathID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.History AS History 
            ON dboStudent.HistoryID = History.HistoryID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.German AS German 
            ON dbo.Student.GermanID = German.GermanID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.LanuageArts AS LanguageArts 
            ON dbo.Student.LanguageArtsID = LanguageArts.LanguageArtsID
```

Comment: If you include your actual query it will be easier for people to give specific suggestions for improvement.

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN, LEFT JOIN and watch your where clause criteria.  you may need to either move it to the join, OR use combinations on them with or statements to handle `(Field = 'X' OR field is Null)` if you just have where Field = 'X' you just invalided the outer joins as no field will have X if there are no matching records!

Answer (score 0):

Two comments:

- Do you know the use of LEFT JOIN?. This query should return all teachers, even thouse with no students.

> SELECT *
>        FROM teacher    t  LEFT JOIN student s ON s.teacher_id = t.id

(RIGHT JOIN would work if you want all student even if they do not have teachers)

- Remmember that in SQL  1 == NULL and 1 != NULL are both false. So the following query will not result a teacher without students or a student without teachers.

> ```
> SELECT *
>      FROM teacher t, 
>           student s
>    WHERE s.teacher_id = t.id
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my answer, in my select i was using dbo.Student.TeacherID, instead of dbo.Teacher.TeacherID, therefore my query was always coming back with null TeacherID values since I was checking my view with a query like this one

```
    Select * from MyView Where TeacherID = 1;
```

This returned null since my select was pulling Student.TeacherID which is null, so I Swapped out dbo.Student.TeacherID for dbo.Teacher.TeacherID and it is now resolved.

Such a bleh moment. Thanks for comments and replies.!

As I am reading back in my OP, I said I was selecting

```
SELECT  Teacher.TeacherID ,
    Student.StudentID ,
```

which was technically a typo, but also my answer...